# Obtaining unique set of related models

Tags: django

I'm attempting to get the NUMBER of unique Employees that are represented within a queryset of jobs. My models are as follows:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Job(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=False)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=False)
```

My query is as follows

```
jobs_list = Job.objects.filter(
                           Q(start_time__lte=start) &
                           Q(end_time__gte=end)
                           )
```

I'd like to develop a query that gets me a unique queryset of Employees that are related to the jobs_list queryset.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways... One of them can be :

```
employee_list = Employee.objects.filter(id__in=Job.objects.filter(
                           Q(start_time__lte=start) &
                           Q(end_time__gte=end)
                           ).values_list('employee__id').distinct())
```

Comment: If possible, I'd like it to all be in one query